# Correctly Structing Vector classes

Tags: java, structure

I'm currently in the process of creating several classes for some basic mathematical functionality [Vector2, Vector3 and Quaternion]. My goal is to make them as intuitive as I can, but not to extensive that it becomes a chore. The one major question I have is:

When doing things such as `void Vector3 add(Vector3 vec)`, should I alter the vector that is being added to or simply create a new vector from the two? In addition, what about things like this `void Vector3 inverse()` - should I make them create separate Vectors to avoid screwing up equation?

Finally, what about `void Vector3 normalize()`, should that create a new instance or simply alter the current Vector3?

Note that the functions are all called on an instance, so the setup is sorta like this `vec.add(vecToApply)` and `vec.inverse()`

Thanks in advance,
  Alec

Comment: Opinion based really.  But my opinion is that these should all create new vectors, rather than modifying their arguments.

Comment: You should make these classes immutable,
 [for all the reasons described here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) and also because that's simply what users of your library will expect.  JDK classes for numeric values (like `Double`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`) are all immutable - yours should be the same.